# url rewriting in php internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have a project runs from localhost i am using wamp local server to run my project.
like localhost/re  re is my project folder how can write in url  rewriting using .htaccess ,
i tried but it throws an error

here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^localhost/re/?$    refer.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "re"
```

and when i run as localhost/re

error is

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

so how can i do it.
Thanks in advance

Amit

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `DirectoryIndex`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /re/

DirectoryIndex refer.php
```

now your default file is `refer.php`

Comment: then also the same error here is my .htaccess file         RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteBase C:/wamp/www/re
RewriteRule    ^localhost/re/?$    us    [NC,L]                     What should i type in my browser after changing it

Comment: directory is C:\wamp\www\re   and on the browser i type localhost/re

Comment: so you want to access `refer.php ` using `localhost/re/re` ?

Comment: if we give localhost/re in wamp it will take automatically  index.php file so actually it will take localhost/re/index.php

Comment: yes default page is index.php, do you want to make your default page refer.php?.. I'm not clear what you want!!

Comment: s i want to change it to refer.php

Comment: no use friend , again the same error. is that matters where we place .htaccess file then where it should be placed either in my project folder or root folder of wamp

Comment: lol.. you must place htaccess in you project folder `re/.htaccess` this will be the location of it

Comment: i just clarified my doubt i have kept it in the re folder only but same error frnd

Comment: here same code is working dear.. now do one thing just remove `re/` from RewriteBase : like... `RewriteBase /`

Comment: frnd i got it i have run rewrite module in apache server from wamp icon in taskbar then it will run  but error has gone but my url havent changed yet

Comment: it redirect to the refer.php or not? or still its index.php?

Comment: did you tried any other redirection before? because i think mod_rewrite is off on your server.

Comment: you can start mod_rewrite in wamp using this.... on wamp on the left hand side click on wamp (lkeeft click) then click on apache and goto modules, click om mod_rewrite so it has a check.

Wait for apache to restart.

Comment: fnd i didnt find mod_rewrite in that apache ver is  2.2.21 wamp version 2.2

Comment: okay... just goto httpd.conf file and then find and replace `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`, restart your server and then run code

Comment: i made the changes but now it showing the complete directory structure not the index.php automatically

Comment: yes now just add `RewriteBase /re/` it will works and make sure refer.php is inside the `re` directory